# MacBook has 2 guest accounts, one with a password that I never set

Tags: macos, user-account

My MacBook Air that I've owned for just days has its own guest account, with its own password. This happened to me once before back in 2013 on a MacBook Pro. Typically, I disable the guest account. However, I recently purchased an open-box MacBook Air from Best Buy. I noticed that sometimes, but not every time, a pixelated Guest account would appear next to my user account when logging in, as seen below:

[image: Photo of login screen with a Guest account and a normal account]

Now most of you might tell me that if I have iCloud & Find My Mac enabled, then the Guest account is there by default. This I'm perfectly aware of, and when I enable Find My Mac, this is what I get:

[image: Photo of login screen with two Guest accounts and a normal account]

Once again, we have a pixelated guest account which is password protected, and then the guest account enabled with Find My Mac (on the far right) which doesn't require a password.

What is going on here?

Comment: What happens if you run the command                                dscl . list /Users | grep -v “^_”   ?      What is does is lists the users. Can you tell us the output from the command? (Note, it shows system users too such as daemon, root, etc..)

Comment: @MatthewN Thanks for the suggestion, here is the output:

Comment: _amavisd
_analyticsd
_appleevents
_applepay
_appowner
_appserver
_appstore
_ard
_assetcache
_astris
_atsserver
_avbdeviced
_calendar
_captiveagent
_ces
_clamav
_cmiodalassistants
_coreaudiod
_coremediaiod
_ctkd
_cvmsroot
_cyrus
_datadetectors
_devdocs
_devicemgr
_displaypolicyd
_distnote
_dovecot
_dovenull
_dpaudio
_eppc
_findmydevice
_fpsd
_ftp
_geod
_hidd
_iconservices
_installassistant
_installer
_jabber
_kadmin_admin
_kadmin_changepw
_krb_anonymous
_krb_changepw
_krb_kadmin
_krb_kerberos
_krb_krbtgt

Comment: _krbfast
_krbtgt
_launchservicesd
_lda
_locationd
_lp
_mailman
_mbsetupuser
_mcxalr
_mdnsresponder
_mobileasset
_mysql
_netbios
_netstatistics
_networkd
_nsurlsessiond
_nsurlstoraged
_ondemand
_postfix
_postgres
_qtss
_sandbox
_screensaver
_scsd
_securityagent
_serialnumberd
_softwareupdate
_spotlight
_sshd
_svn
_taskgated
_teamsserver
_timed
_timezone
_tokend
_trustevaluationagent
_unknown
_update_sharing
_uucp
_warmd
_webauthserver
_windowserver
_www
_wwwproxy
_xserverdocs
daemon
nobody
opancollc
root
opancollcs-MacBook-Air:~ opancollc$

Comment: I ran this on my computer and compared the results. Our computers have all the same users (except mine has a different username obviously and I also have the guest account enable). So this account isn't listed as a user in the computer. So then I wonder why it appears...

Comment: Are you an admin on the computer??

Comment: @MatthewN  The account no longer appears. I deleted the computer & did a fresh reinstall. Not the first time that this happened though. As far as whether or not I am an admin, I am. It’s my computer. But just as the guest user shows up password protected, I’ve had other instances whereby I go to login to my computer, only to get a message which says, “This account has been disabled by the system administrator.” I quit taking it into Apple back in 2015, and the problem has been ongoing since 2013 - with at least on average one occurrence per year. It’s super disenchanting, as you can imagine...

Comment: I would consider downloading an antivirus program to make sure that you aren’t accidentally downloading a virus which is causing this.

Comment: So now considering that I am the only admin on the machine, and someone has the ability to add their own “guest account” that I can’t control, or literally lock me out of my own account, I finally came to the point of giving up. It took some time getting used to the fact that I no longer have a reasonable expectation of privacy, which is so easily taken for granted. I feel ethically compelled to explain to each of my clients that I can’t take credit cards, nor manage passwords - as I’m too much of a liability to their business.

Comment: @MathewN this is not virus. This is a human. I’m very confident about this, and have a relatively good idea who is behind it - which is beside the point. No matter what type of Mac, or happy OS updates have been released- if I so much as turn on iCloud, it will show that there are 2 versions of my computer. One shows the user name & exact type of computer. The other one just says “Username +Mac” without stating whether it’s a MBPro, Air, iMac, etc. clearly, they are able to copy my keychain or certificates - but now I’m getting into stuff I don’t understand. I don’t know jack about computers.

Comment: Ok, I at least recommend you change all your passwords related to your Apple ID, this includes any password managers you use, your email password and you Apple ID password. Also an anti-virus program can possibly prevent attacks from the person who you believe is doing this. If you want to try to protect you computer and don't want to go to any stores, feel free to ask me. I'm always glad to help.

Comment: A couple hours ago i had the same issue
A suspicious password locked guest account appeared. When i open settings there was no guest account. However each time while opening mac os it was asking me which account you wanna open. There were 3 accounts
- Suspicious password locked guest account (my password didnt open it) - My account - Guess account (safari only) Immediatly i deleted mac os. I didnt even get backups and now im installing a time machine backup which is from 10 days ago. I hope I dont get in any trouble

Comment: @Sinan why would you get into any trouble?

Answer (score 3):

If I purchased a open box computer, The first thing I would do is erase the entire internal drive and reinstall the operating system.

My preferred method, for erasing and reinstalling, is to use a flash drive. The instructions are given at [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

Once booted from the flash drive, I usually erase all previous partitions and create a single partition for the installation of macOS. This can be done by using Disk Utility application included on the flash drive. More information can be found at [How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904). Look for the section "*Decide whether to erase your startup disk*".

Comment: I'm liking the feedback. In no way am I shooting this down, it's logical and makes sense. However, I've done this. First, I'd like to note that I never purchase open box computers. Open box or not, the issues will appear when they do. I have found that the less attention that I give to these problems, the quicker they subside. From February 2014 thru May 2014 - I made a huge mistake by giving this all of my attention, and subsequently, the problems persisted until I finally gave up the fight. I got a new computer, completely exhausted and beat down - gave the symptoms no attention & it stops.

Comment: Here's another that I would love for someone to explain - Apple sends me a warning 1 time per computer that says - "Another computer on this network is using this computers IP Address." WTF? How is this possible. I came home from work to find my MacMini powered on, and the pop-up was right in the middle of the screen, followed by another message from Apple, "Please contact your system administrator." Once again, who the hell is my sysadmin?

Comment: I suppose the system administrator (sysadmin) would be someone who could assign your computer a different IP address if your Local Area Network (LAN) is using fixed IP addresses. Alternatively, if your LAN is using dynamic IP addresses, then the sysadmin could change the DHCP reservation in the router, so your computer would be assigned a different IP address.  So I guess the sysadmin is someone who decides how everything connected to your LAN is assigned an IP address. It is the sysadmin's job to make sure each IP address is unique. In your case, you get to be the sysadmin. Good Luck.

Comment: @DavidAnderson What you are saying is logical, however keep in mind it's just my fiance & I living in a small apartment. Someone must have intricate knowledge of how our internet provider works, as this is a remote attack. Several times when my computer freezes and I try to force quit everything but nothing moves, I hold down the power buttin. If finder is open during this time, a Remote System Administrator will fash in the sidebar of finder prior to the computer shutting down.

Comment: @JoshSalganik see ["Another device on the network is using your computer's IP address"](http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/19/another-device-on-the-network-is-using-your-computers-ip-address/)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the pixelated “Guest Account” is just another user account  possibly created when the computer was at BestBuy. If your the administrator (which you should be) of the computer you should remove be able to remove the other account in settings.

Comment: This "guest account" did not appear in "users" neither when I enabled nor disabled the account. Furthermore, I was not able to even find the account when I launched into recovery mode, opened terminal, and attempted to use the resetpassword command.

Comment: @JoshSalganik That seems very suspicious... I would recommend running a anti virus like AVG or Avast to make sure you don't have any viruses, if it doesn't find any and you can't figure out how to remove it I could recommend brining it to an apple store

Comment: Thank you for your advice. In fact, I did just that. I don't want to give off the wrong vibe - I'm a die hard apple fanatic - but I have not been impressed with those "geniuses" over at the bar. In fact, they had the most "genius" genius look at it and tell me that it was something that I must have done.

Comment: @JoshSalganik Same opinion on the "geniuses" as well, I just ran out of other ideas. If you said you got the computer at best buy you might have some kind of warranty from them, I would check possibly with them about your situation.

Comment: This question has captured my intrigue and I'm now very curious to know who has the answer. @MatthewN - just a thought but wouldn't the more sophisticated "hacker" (assuming this is the result of a targeted threat) find a way to make their "work" invisible to those anti-virus software programs?

Comment: @Taylor technically if they were to find a virus/exploit that wasn’t in the anti viruses dictionary(list of viruses/malware) they wouldn’t be detected, but if it was a hacker it wouldn’t make sense for them to make a visible user to access the computer. It would be easier and safer for them  to just enable a the root user and access it.

Comment: @MatthewN Good point. But in such a scenario, what if a hacker actually wanted the user to know they were being hacked by leaving some sort of "clue" (such as with the mysterious guest user accounts) but still made it so their work (virus/exploit) was undetectable (through root access, for example)? Is this even possible?

Comment: @Taylor In what case would a hacker who had already gained root privileges and gained control of the system want to let the owner know “Hey buddy, I’ve hacked your computer”? There is no point of leaving a clue that they’ve compromised the system.  If you can think of a reason why please let me know, I’d actually want to know if there’s a reason why’d they do that.

Comment: @JoshSalganik Have you attempted a anti-virus scan or brought it into any repair shops to get it checked out?

Comment: @MatthewN I agree but say a supposed hacker gains access to a specific computer and out of spite/revenge (maybe he/she/it knows the "victim") uses tactics to "torment" the victim, knowing that the victim simply lacks the knowledge to fix the problem and thus is rendered helpless. What I'm trying to infer suggests something along the lines of "Hey buddy, look what I can do, and guess what? You cant stop me!" Am I drifting completely off course with this one?

Comment: @Taylor That does make a lot of sense actually, thanks for mentioning it.

But of course I somehow have an counter argument. If he's trying to torment the victim. In this case, why not make it more obvious then adding a guest user with an odd account picture? When he could literally make an infinite pop-up message with an annoying message. If you ask me thats a pretty good way to torment someone and let them know that they go into their system.

Comment: @MatthewN Hmm... pop-ups vs. mysterious guest accounts...I'm still very curious to know what really is causing the issue here. I suppose whichever method a hacker would use to torment its victim would ultimately depend on the extent of their own abilities/imagination? "My" supposed hacker didn't think of/know how to implement endless pop-ups...that certainly would be more effective than a random guest account though.

Answer (score -2):

The guest account means you have "Find My Mac" on. Turn off "Find My Mac" and it will disappear.

Comment: OP has already mentioned Find My Mac in the question, and states that enabling Find My Mac adds another Guest User separate to the one this question is about.